# PHP: remove extra space from a string using regex

Tags: php, regex, string, whitespace

How do I remove extra spaces **at the end** of a string using regex (preg_replace)?

```
$string = "some random text with extra spaces at the end      ";
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no need of regex here and you can use [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) for it, its cleaner and faster:

```
$str = rtrim($str);
```

But if you want a regex based solution you can use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s*$/','',$str);
```

The regex used is `/\s*$/`

- `\s` is short for any white space
  char, which includes space.
- `*` is the quantifier for zero or
  more
- `$` is the end anchor

Basically we replace trailing whitespace characters with nothing (`''`), effectively deleting them.

Comment: Instead of `*` quantifier, you could use `+` quantifier to avoid replace nothing by nothing.

Answer (score 10):

You don't really need regex here, you can use the [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) function.

```
$string = "some random text with extra spaces at the end      ";
$string = rtrim($string);
```

[Code on ideone](http://ideone.com/TlswE)

---

**See also :**

- [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
- [ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

Comment: Heh, I'd like to know too, +1 to set things right with the universe.

Comment: +1 since this answer is maybe less fascinating, but the right one!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use trim() to do this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: Sorry... missed "AT THE END". As the others pointed out... rtrim()

Comment: @LarsH, Didn't want to edit it to be the same as the other in case the trim() option may work for future searchers, but point taken...thx