# Removing whitespaces and newline characters from GraphQL based on condition

Tags: regex, pcre, vcl, fastly

I am trying to remove extra whitespaces and newline characters from my GraphQL query but the data between 2 double quotes in **filter** argument should remain intact.

Here's how the query is received on our fastly's CDN

```
# input
{"query":"query OpName    {\n   itemCollection         (filter: { text: "aa aa     aa", text2: "aa             aa"}){\n    group         {      slug\n\n\n\n            text text2  } }   }"}

# expected output
{"query":"query OpName { itemCollection (filter: { text: "aa aa     aa", text2: "aa             aa"}){ group { slug text text2 } } }"}
```

The objective is to

- Remove extra whitespaces from the query
- The whitespaces between 2 double quotes, should remain intact inside the graphql query (since the **filter** argument's value will be used to match records in our database)

We have tried the following:

- `\s+(?=(?:['|%22](?:\\['|%22]|[^'|%22])+['|%22]|[^'|%22])+$)` given at [fastly docs](https://developer.fastly.com/solutions/recipes/cache-graphql-query-response)
- `\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)`

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: remove extra space from a string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763439/php-remove-extra-space-from-a-string-using-regex)

Comment: It doesn't. There's a condition where the whitespace and newlines should not be removed. Blindly removing all whitespaces from the query breaks it while parsing.

Comment: Try `\s+(?=([^\x22]*[\x22][^\x22]*[\x22])*[^\x22]*$)` https://regex101.com/r/QZlB09/1

Comment: Sorry, but the above doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it in 3 steps:

- save the `filter` temporarily;
- make the replacements (delete the unwanted spaces);
- add back the `filter`.

The required regexes become significantly simpler (and I guess faster, as you do not need look-aheads or other tricks).

---

Alternative:

Split the string in 3 parts:

- before `filter`;
- `filter`;
- after `filter`.

Make the replacements in the "before" and "after" strings. Join the parts at the end.

---

The [regex for splitting](https://regex101.com/r/hicA6L/2) might look like:

```
(.*?)(filter: {[^}]*})(.*)
```

Rebuild the final string with something as:

```
removeSpaces(group1) + group2 + removeSpaces(group3)
```

`removeSpaces()` actually replaces `\s+` with  . If you want to keep new lines (`\n`), then replace  `+` with  .

I am not very familiar with your programming language, so I cannot provide the exact code, but you should be able to get the idea.

Comment: the argument for filter is of type JSON object, thus it can have any combination of keys and values. Thus, I am only concerned that the value of the JSON keys are not distorted when the whitespace is being removed.

Comment: It does not matter. You isolate `filter` with `filter: {[^}]*}`. As long as the JSON does not contain curly braces, you are safe. BTW, what is the source of those strings with many spaces? You might be able to remove the spaces before the string is build, and thus save time and effort, and increase speed.

Comment: The filter's JSON could be like this as well: `{text: "text value", group: {key: "value", arr: ["a", 1]}}`. Thus, the regex provided won't fully work. The regex is in PCRE. Language is Varnish - VCL

Comment: The JSON has only one level of curly braces, or they can be embedded for any number of levels?

Comment: I fear that you are actually in the situation to need proper parsers for SQL and for JSON.